# I want to open File & Media Storage permissions for App in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-intent, linker

[image: I want this screen directly open from the code.Any Solution?]

> I have tried this code but it opens the app Settings.

```
Linking.openSettings();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution for Android Only - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-open-settings

Comment: But this only open the Phone settings not opens the particular Storage permission of the specific app that i want to open.